# Tuple of colons in ndarray slicing

Tags: python, indexing, slice, numpy-ndarray

In NumPy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) we see a Note in the beginning:

> In Python, x[(exp1, exp2, ..., expN)] is equivalent to x[exp1, exp2, ..., expN]; the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former.

Why doesn't x[(:,:)] work instead of x[:,:] then? For example if the concatenation of slices is needed, one must use a[(0,) + (slice(None),)]  instead of a[(0,) + (:,)]

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Please provide some code samples, so it will be more straightforward to answer, I guess there may be some mess  with the usage of `:` and `,`

Comment: Thanks, @AndriyIvaneyko! Here's the example: let `v = np.arange(24); v.shape = (2,3,4)`. Then v[1,0,:] works as usual, while `v[(1,0,:)]` produces SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the names of the variables `exp1, exp2, ... expN` imply, this works for expressions only. However, `:` by itself is not an expression, so `(:,)` is a syntax error because the colon symbol can only be used in indexing in this sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @ForceBru. However, what about e.g. `v[ 0, 2, 0:3:2 ]` which works and  `v[(0, 2, 0:3:2)]` which causes SyntaxError

Comment: I think I got it kinda like this: First the interpreter tries to comprehend a tuple (:, ) in which a colon itself **or any expression like `start:stop:step`** makes no sense.

Comment: @VladimirBaturin, right, in the first case, the colons are just syntactic sugar that builds an object of type `slice`. However, this construct is only valid when doing some kind of indexing, it doesn't make sense when constructing tuples like in your second example.